# How to deny/ban the use of certain external functions

Tags: rust

I have a rust project which multiple people work on.
There are certain problematic functions defined by external crates we use, that is the source of a lot of confusion and errors.
I want to totally deny/ban the use of these functions crate-wide at compile time.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`disallowed_method`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#disallowed_method) Clippy lint to accomplish this. (There's also [`disallowed_type`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#disallowed_type) for types.)

For example, to disallow `Box::new`:

```rust
#![deny(clippy::disallowed_method)]

fn main() {
    let my_box = Box::new(123);
}
```

Add this to `clippy.toml` in the workspace root:

```toml
disallowed-methods = [
    # fully qualified function/method name:
    "std::boxed::Box::new",
]
```

When you then run `cargo clippy`, you will get an error about the usage of the disallowed function:

```
error: use of a disallowed method `alloc::boxed::Box::new`
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |   let my_box = Box::new(123);
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
```

Comment: This clippy is now named 'clippy::disallowed_methods', so add this to the top of your main.rs:

```#![deny(clippy::disallowed_methods)]```